# Double integrals on polynomial with variable in python

Tags: python

How am I supposed to calculate the following double integral in python and get a result in terms of t
[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kK6Q.png)

f(x) and g(y) are polynomials.

Comment: How would you do it without Python?

Comment: f(x) and g(y) are polynomials and the integral can be calculated directly. For example, you can suppose f(x)=x, g(y)=y

Comment: And what would be the result in terms of t?

Comment: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Bt%7D%5Cint_%7Bt%2Bx%7D%5E%7B1%7Dxydydx) I can solve using Worfram Alpha, but I want to automate the process in python

Comment: The first step would be to design how to represent the polynomials and the integration with Python data structures. Then write functions which take these as input and do the symbolic math.

Comment: thanks I understand, but I was asking if there is any library that already does that.

Comment: Okay, actually you weren't exactly asking that, but yes, there is such a library.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506748/symbolic-mathematics-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g. using sympy:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False)
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> y = Symbol('y')
>>> t = Symbol('t')
>>> integrate(integrate(x * y, (y, t + x, 1)), (x, 0, t))
      4      /     2\
  11*t     2 |1   t |
- ----- + t *|- - --|
    24       \4   4 /
>>>
```

See: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html